# "Agreement Score"

Tags: similarities, agreement-statistics, polling

I have a dataset of legislative roll call votes.

This dataset contains the votes of all members of Congress during on specific period (in this case, 2 years). The data is mounted according this following structure:

**Legislator A**: N | - | - | Y | Y | N

**Legislator B**: N | - | Y | Y | Y | N

**Legislator C**: Y | Y | Y | N | - | Y

I am trying to figure out how measure an 'agreement score' that indicates what is correlation of voting behavior between each legislator-pair. So, based on this score, I could indicates that A is more similar of B than C, for example.

My first idea was to calculate how many times a pair of members voted equally divided by the total of times that the two have the opportunity to vote:

**AgreementScore** (A/B) =  X/Y

X = number of times have voted similarly on all roll call votes

Y = all possible eligible opportunities to do so

But this strategy, in my opinion is weak.

Considering that there were 110 polls and two legislator John and Mary, voted equal on 80/100 opportunities and at the same time John and Ryan voted equal on 5/6 opportunities, if I just analysis this score John and Ryan are more similar(83%) than John and Mary(80%). However I am not putting on account the total of votes of each legislator neither the total of roll calls of the dataset.

I don`t know if I can say that John and Mary are more similar than John and Ryan, based on statistics perspective.

I am racing around like a chicken with its head cut off trying to figure out how to improve this score due my lack of knowledge and experience on statistics.

Do you have some guidance or suggestion to handle this problem?

Comment: Such data must have been analyzed before, did you look at some papers?   http://www.jstor.org/stable/2111445?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents    I would start with a few susch papers, then maybe ideas related to correspondence analysis, chisquare distance, ...

Answer (score 1):

A usual way to approach the question would be to not only compute the ratio but also the width of the confidence interval:

```
> john.and.mary <- binom.test(80, 100)
> john.and.mary$conf.int
[1] 0.7081573 0.8733444
>
> john.and.ryan <- binom.test(5, 6)
> john.and.ryan$conf.int
[1] 0.3587654 0.9957893
```

That way it is very clear how much we know about both pairs' agreement. As for your goal, maybe we can reformulate things:

You appear to start off with some assumption of two legislators voting differently (or maybe as a start 50/50?) and then from vote to cote you want to gain more confidence in them voting similarly. In that case, it becomes a Bayesian question. You can and have to formulate a prior indicating, how strong you want your initial belief (maybe 50/50) to be and than compute Bayes probabilities:
([beta distribution being conjugate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution#Bayesian_inference) we use that)

```
prior <- \(x) dbeta(x, 3, 3)
john.and.mary <- \(x) dbeta(x, 3+80, 3+20)
john.and.ryan <- \(x) dbeta(x, 3+5, 3+1)

curve(prior, ylim = c(0,10))
curve(john.and.mary, col = "green", add  = TRUE)
curve(john.and.ryan, col = "blue", add = TRUE)
legend(x = "topleft", fill = c("black", "green", "blue"),
       legend = c("prior", "John and Mary", "John and Ryan"))
```

[image]

The [mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution#Mode) of each curve might make a suitable agreement/disagreement measure. Off course you will have to decide whether 50/50 votes is a natural starting point. Maybe 40% of the votes are not even necessary as they are not really choices but everyone has the same opinion so the natural point of "just 50% agreement in votes where your individual opinion counts" is 70%? However, the point is that consensual votes draw the mode in direction of the mode and dissenting ones draw the mode away from the prior mode and 8 out of 10 has less of an influence the 80 out of 100.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should consider two different measures to define the agreement between two persons. The first measure is the ratio of agreement between these two persons (such as the **AgreementScore** you have defined), and the second is the number of opportunities that these persons had. This is similar to **support** and **confidence** measures in association rule mining. The support measures the **coverage** of the rule and the confidence assesses the **accuracy** of the rule.

Comment: How I would join these measures (the support and the confidence) in an end value, from 0 to 100?